# Which is the fastest way to return the number of different rows in a matrix A?

Tags: c++, matrix

If i have the following matrix A:

```
A = {1,2,3}
    {7,9,1}
    {5,3,2}
```

how i can easily return the number of different rows in the Matrix? In this case the output must be : "3"

i tried to make a function "**rows**":

```
void rows (int a[N][N], int row[N], int x){

    for (int i=0;i<N;i++){

        row[i]=a[x][i];


    }

}
```

then, with the function "**check**" i tried to check if the rows are different:

```
int check ( int a[N][N])
{

    int row1[N];
    int row2[N];

    int j=0;

    rows(a,row1,j);
    rows(a,row2,j+1); 


    int count = 0;


    for ( int i=0; i<N; i++){
        for ( int j=0; j<N; j++){


            if ( row1[i] != row2[j]){

                count++;

            }

        }
    }


    return count;

}
```

but return the wrong number , any suggestions ?

Comment: returned number very big than 3? lets say 9?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your algorithm is entirely wrong. With an added `break` it "works" when all rows are different, but it breaks when some of the rows are the same. It counts the number of rows such that there exists another row that's different from it. For example, if you run it on

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
1 2 3
```

you will get an answer `3`, but you should get a `2`.

The algorithm should go like this:

- Assume that all rows are distinct (`result = N`)
- For each row `i`, look at the rows below it
- If any of the rows `j` below the row `i` is equal to `row[i]`, decrement the `result` and break out of the inner loop
- At the end of the outer loop, `result` contains your answer.

Comment: yep , this is the correct way , i thought only now that only the first example works, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

try to add inequality variable into:

```
int count = 0;


for ( int i=0; i<N; i++){
inequalty=0;
    for ( int j=0; j<N; j++){


        if ( row1[i] != row2[j]){

            inequality=1;
            break; //this makes even faster

        }

    }
 if(inequality!=0)count++;
}
```

even a single element's inequality makes the row inequal right?

Comment: @osiris_0100 but this still only looks at the first two rows. Did you try other examples?

Comment: @Henrik mhmh you're right, if i change and put the first and the third rows as equal it doesn't works :|

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık this doesn't really fix it. You should delete this answer.

Comment: because it gives number of "same rows" edited to make it "different rows". just changed == with != at the last part

Answer (score 1):

Implement a 'CompareRows' functor as a predicate for set.  Then, all you need to do is --

```
typedef vector<int> Rows;
set<Rows, CompareRows> UniqRows;

for ( int i = 0 ; i < N ; ++i )
  UniqRows.insert(Rows(a[i], a[i] + N));

UniqRows.size();
```